# WCF 500 error on IIS without logging to Event Log

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, service

I have faced to odd error, does anybody know what this means?
This service works normally from VS2010 but breaks on IIS.
Unfortunately i could not google what is the meaning of this error code...

```
Module  ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0
Error Code  0x800703e9
```

Trace for WCF looks like :

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing, Critical, Error, Warning"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing, Critical, Error, Warning">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="D:\Trace.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

And result of the tracing :

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131073</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
<Level>8</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-02T12:52:40.5061619Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="3584" ThreadID="2" />
<Channel />
<Computer>ANAZAROV</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.AppDomainUnload.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>AppDomain unloading.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-2-129673033336784854</AppDomain>
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord">
<AppDomain.FriendlyName>/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-2-129673033336784854</AppDomain.FriendlyName>
<ProcessName>w3wp</ProcessName>
<ProcessId>3584</ProcessId>
</ExtendedData>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Thanks, Art

**ANSWER IS FOUND !!!**

This extension needs to be installed : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension needs to be installed : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

Answer (score 2):

You can enable tracing on your service and then check the place where your web service is failing. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). Also try to invoke the web service from IE and see what the stack trace says. Else post the stack trace for more help.

Comment: I have updated my question with Log attachment ... though i cannot see any useful information there ...

Comment: When you open up the trace file do you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: Can you check if your application is built using .NET 4.0 framework rather than .NET 4.0 client profile. Also make sure that the app pool on IIS is v4.0 (hopefully you are using .NET framework 4 else the needs to be the one you are using)

Answer (score 0):

Quick search shows that error means "Stack overflow". Overflow exceptions are special - in most cases you won't be able to debug them.

You should take a look at your code and check for recursion calls - they may cause an overflow if used without restrictions on recursion depth.

Comment: The problem is that this service normally works on other machines ... so code is OK, this is some problem with IIS / PC configuration ...